# Accessing IMDB dataset in AWS in R, Python or Java

Tags: java, python, r, api, amazon-s3

I am trying to connect to IMDB dataset in AWS.
I've already signed up for AWS and set up the credential.

I'm more familiar with R and apparently there's R package called aws.s3. And when I used s3HTTP function, I get errors as below

```
s3HTTP(verb="GET", bucket="imdb-datasets", path="documents/v1/current/name.basics.tsv.gz",
   request_body = "documents/v1/current/name.basics.tsv.gz",
   headers=list('x-amz-request-payer' = "requester"),
   key=Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"="*******"), secret=Sys.setenv("AWS_SECRET_KEY"="******"))

List of 5
 $ Code          : chr "InvalidAccessKeyId"
 $ Message       : chr "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not 
exist in our records."
 $ AWSAccessKeyId: chr "TRUE"
 $ RequestId     : chr "234D5ED951AD2468"
 $ HostId        : chr "ugVtbV2Qz6NrNFD7ODO84MnzYttftsjHwbAawExo75Bg9xq3JAXOuDqF8GcYLd5vD6TgcHe/ib4="
 - attr(*, "headers")=List of 6
  ..$ x-amz-request-id : chr "234D5ED951AD2468"
  ..$ x-amz-id-2       : chr "ugVtbV2Qz6NrNFD7ODO84MnzYttftsjHwbAawExo75Bg9xq3JAXOuDqF8GcYLd5vD6TgcHe/ib4="
  ..$ content-type     : chr "application/xml"
  ..$ transfer-encoding: chr "chunked"
  ..$ date             : chr "Mon, 20 Nov 2017 08:37:13 GMT"
  ..$ server           : chr "AmazonS3"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "aws_error"
 - attr(*, "request_canonical")= chr "GET\n/imdb-
datasets/\nlocation=\nhost:s3.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-
date:20171120T083712Z\n\nhost;x-amz-date\ne3b0c44"| __truncated__
 - attr(*, "request_string_to_sign")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-
SHA256\n20171120T083712Z\n20171120/us-east-
1/s3/aws4_request\n760638139d8fa8fa1e36b824f481abe59184955"| __truncated__
 - attr(*, "request_signature")= chr "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 
 Credential=TRUE/20171120/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, 
SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=b"| __truncated__
NULL
```

My access key is up to date and I have no problem accessing my own bucket.
I also copied the java example codes provided by IMDB on their webpage (http://www.imdb.com/interfaces/), and it seemed to be compiling without errors, but there's no file downloaded in my bucket in AWS.

Comment: But you haven't shown your R code.